# point such that area to the right of that point under one gaussian is 5% of area under a second gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

Say I have two gaussian random variables $Z_1 \sim f_1 = f(\cdot|\mu_1, \sigma_1)$ and $Z_2 \sim f(\cdot|\mu_2, \sigma_2) = f_2$, where $f$ is the gaussian density. How can I calculate the value of $x$ such that the area under $f_2$ to the right of $x$ is $Y$ times greater than the area under $f_1$  to the right of $x$ (say I can assume that $f_2$ is right of $f_1$). Specifically, I am interested in $Y=19$.

Comment: Please clarify the notation. Are $f_1$ and $f_2$ cumulative distribution functions or densities? Or the random variables themselves?

Answer (score 1):

You can analyze this graphically with a [ROC curve](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Curves_in_ROC_space) which relates as well to areas under Gaussian curves to the right of some value.

[image: plot of ROC]

You will be looking for the point where the ROC curve intersects the diagonal given by $P(TP) = Y\cdot  P(FP)$ (There can be zero, one, or two solutions).

You can do this easily computationally with a search algorithm. I doubt that there is an analytical solution.